# Regular Expression to capture only if all preceding lines have a keyword

Tags: regex

I want to have a regular expression that will only match on the CLPM_FPGA_xx ID if the preceding lines all start with the keyword 'PASS'

If any of the preceding lines start with the word 'FAIL', then the CLPM_FPGA_xx ID should not be extracted

I thought it would be relatively be easy but since the number of preceding lines is variable and the FAIL line could be first, last or in the middle, I've struggled

Any suggestions appreciated.

== Example Data ========

PASS: PLL Lock signal state at reset is 0.
PASS: PLL Lock signal state is 1.
PASS: PLL Locked within expected time: 5000000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_31

PASS: System Clock high period is 8000 ps.
FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
PASS: System Clock period is 16000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_32

PASS: System Clock to IFC delay is 10 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_31

PASS: System Clock to IFC delay is 10 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_34

FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
PASS: System Clock high period is 8000 ps.
PASS: System Clock period is 16000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_32

PASS: System Clock high period is 8000 ps.
PASS: System Clock period is 16000 ps.
FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_32

FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_33

=====================================
Reg Exp Attempt :
^(?!(FAIL:|Requirements)).*(\n^PASS:.*)+\nRequirements verified:[ \t]+(CLPM_FPGA_.*)

but this matches on the occurrences where there is a PASS coming immediately after a FAIL

Comment: Can you share the RegExp you've already written in an attempt to satisfy the requirement described? [ask]

Comment: Here is my current attempt :   https://regex101.com/r/jjfPA4/1

Comment: Can you include that in the body of your post as a [mre]? External links tend to change/break over time and nuke all value for future visitors to this post. See [ask]

Comment: @GraemeJessiman, at least 3 solutions of your problem can be found here [Regex pattern to catch 'ID' in text blocks without 'FAIL' status (regex only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71779891/regex-pattern-to-catch-id-in-text-blocks-without-fail-status-regex-only#71779979)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to split text on blocks, filter out blocks with 'FAIL' status and then find id.

Note: I've replaced ids with non duplicated numbers (from 31 to 37) for better control of matching.

Possible solution is the following:

```
import re

string = """PASS: PLL Lock signal state at reset is 0.
PASS: PLL Lock signal state is 1.
PASS: PLL Locked within expected time: 5000000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_31

PASS: System Clock high period is 8000 ps.
FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
PASS: System Clock period is 16000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_32

PASS: System Clock to IFC delay is 10 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_33

PASS: System Clock to IFC delay is 10 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_34

FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
PASS: System Clock high period is 8000 ps.
PASS: System Clock period is 16000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_35

PASS: System Clock high period is 8000 ps.
PASS: System Clock period is 16000 ps.
FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_36

FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_37"""

string_blocks = string.split("\n\n")


re_pattern = re.compile(r"PASS.+\n.+CLPM_FPGA_(\d+)$", re.M)

result = []

for string_block in string_blocks:
    if 'FAIL' not in string_block:
        found = re_pattern.findall(string_block)
        result.extend(found)

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
['31', '33', '34']
```

Comment: That also matches where one of the preceding lines start with FAIL. It should only match when the lines immediately above all start with PASS.   In my example dataset, only the 1st, 3rd & 4th IDs should get extracted since all of the others are preceded by a line starting with FAIL

Comment: Let me try and explain that better           The suggested regexp also matches where one of the preceding lines start with FAIL. It should only match when the set of PASS/FAIL lines above all start with PASS.   In my example dataset, only the 1st, 3rd & 4th IDs should get extracted since all of the others are preceded by at least one of  the lines starting with FAIL.  The 2nd dataset comprises 4 lines. The first 3 lines start  PASS, FAIL, PASS so the 4th line should not be matched

Comment: @GraemeJessiman, please take a look at the updated code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I can only execute a single line regex in the tool i'm using, so this solution won't work for me. I get the feeling that I can't do what I need without a more complex script.

Comment: @GraemeJessiman, I'll think about regex only solution