# Regex pattern to catch 'ID' in text blocks without 'FAIL' status (regex only)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need to write a regular expression that will catch `ids` in the **CLPM_FPGA_`id`** substring if there is **no** `FAIL` status in the text block.
The solution should have `regex pattern only` (split and other python methods are not allowed).

```
import re

string = """PASS: PLL Lock signal state at reset is 0.
PASS: PLL Lock signal state is 1.
PASS: PLL Locked within expected time: 5000000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_31

PASS: System Clock high period is 8000 ps.
FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
PASS: System Clock period is 16000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_32

PASS: System Clock to IFC delay is 10 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_33

PASS: System Clock to IFC delay is 10 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_34

FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
PASS: System Clock high period is 8000 ps.
PASS: System Clock period is 16000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_35

PASS: System Clock high period is 8000 ps.
PASS: System Clock period is 16000 ps.
FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_36

FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_37

PASS: System Clock to IFC delay is 10 ps.
FAIL: System Clock low period is 8000 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_38

PASS: System Clock to IFC delay is 10 ps.
Requirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_39"""

re_pattern = re.compile("(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\n{2}))PASS.+?(?!FAIL).+?CLPM_FPGA_(\d{2})", re.I|re.S)

found = re_pattern.findall(string)

found
```

**My solution returns**

```
['31', '32', '33', '34', '36', '38', '39']
```

[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zzTwd6/1)

**The expected result should be**

```
['31', '33', '34', '39']
```

**Collect and Ignore rules for text blocks**

[image]

Do you have any suggestions how to omit the text blocks with `FAIL` status from regex pattern results?

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'(?:\n{2}|^)PASS(?=(?:.*\n(?!FAIL:))*.*(?:\n{2}|$))(?:.+\n)*.+CLPM_FPGA_(\d{2})', text, re.I)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
(?:\A|\n{2})PASS:.*(?:\nPASS:.*)*\n(?!FAIL:).*CLPM_FPGA_(\d+)
```

- `(?:\A|\n{2})` Match either the start of the string or 2 newlines
- `PASS:.*` Match `PASS:` and the rest of the line
- `(?:\nPASS:.*)*` Optionally repeat all lines that start with PASS:
- `\n` Match a newline
- `(?!FAIL:)` Assert not FAIL: directly to the right
- `.*CLPM_FPGA_(\d+)` Match the line with CLPM_FPGA_ and capture 1+ digits in group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y0S926/1)

```
re_pattern = re.compile("(?:\A|\n{2})PASS:.*(?:\nPASS:.*)*\n(?!FAIL:).*CLPM_FPGA_(\d+)", re.I)
found = re_pattern.findall(string)

print(found)
```

Output

```
['31', '33', '34', '39']
```

Answer (score 1):

The following approach using `re.findall` seemed to work for me:

```py
matches = re.findall(r'(?:\n{2,}|^)PASS:.*?(?:\nPASS:.*?)*?\nRequirements verified: CLPM_FPGA_(\d+)', string)
print(matches)  # ['31', '33', '34', '39']
```

The strategy of this regex is to match blocks, indicated by a starting `PASS` which itself is preceded by either two spaces or the start of the string.  It then matches *only* subsequent `PASS` lines, followed by the requirements line.  We capture the ID which then appears in the output list.